# SQL Server 2008 Query Result Formating (changing x and y axis fields)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

What is the most efficient way to format query results, wether in the actual SQL Server SQL code or using a different program such as access or excel so that the X (first row column headers) and Y Axis (first column field values) can be changed, but with the same query result data still being represented, just in a different way.

they way the data is stored in my database and they way my original query results are returned in SQL Server 2008 are as follows:

[Original Results Format](http://goals-success-motivation.com/FL_Earned_Exposures_2011.htm)

And Below is the way I need to have the data look:

[How I need the Results to Look](http://goals-success-motivation.com/FL_Earned_Exposures_2011_B.htm)

In essence, I need to have the zipcode field go down the Y Axis (first column) and the Coveragecode field to go across the top first Row (X Axis) with the exposures filling in the rest of the data.

The only way I can thing of getting this done is by bringing the data into excel and doing a bunch of V-LookUps. I tried using some pivot tables but didn't get to far. I'm going to continue trying to format the data using the V-LookUps but hopefully someone can come up with a better way of doing this.

Comment: Just a heads up - It would serve others better if you posted the data in your question rather than referencing external links - plus you will typically get more responses/activity that way.

Comment: @J Cooper: can you give a SO-meta link to support your adivce? It does not sound obvious/clear-cut.

Comment: @zespri - my advice is based on the fact that if the external links die, it will not be as easy to understand the question being asked. Also, as far as more activity, it is my observation that questions which depend on external links (or links for that matter) receive less attention - case in point, this relatively easy question to answer did not have any comments or answers 10 hours after it was asked.

Comment: Believe me, I wanted to put the data in the question but i don't see how I can add a table to my question. I tried using html codes but it did not allow me to put any cellpadding or cellspacing in the cells (and it would have taken a long time to create the html code and to populate both tables). I would have much rather preferred to be able to put the tabular data in the question as you suggest as opposed to having the upload those html files. Any advice/links on how to add the tabular data to a question (so that it is aligned appropriately)?

Comment: @JuanVelez - you can use the same monospaced formatting that is used for code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a table operator called `PIVOT`. Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

```
WITH Src AS(
    SELECT Coveragecode, Zipcode, EarnedExposers
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT Zipcode, [BI], [PD], [PIP], [UMBI], [COMP], [COLL]
FROM Src
PIVOT(MAX(EarnedExposers) FOR CoverageCode 
    IN(
           [BI], 
           [PD], 
           [PIP], 
           [UMBI], 
           [COMP], 
           [COLL]
      )
) AS P;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already did it the long way (bringing the data into excel and doing a BUNCH of vlookups and then putting into access and remove the duplicate records ::sigh::) but I will try this method out now anyway. It will save me a lot of time in the future!

Comment: i was able to use the above code recently. Worked great. Thanks again J Cooper!